# interface authentication

Tags: android, authentication, interface, runtime-error

I have created an interface of authentication (login and password). and this is the code:

```
package com.example.exercice1part2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String login="aaa";
private String pwd="bbb";
private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;
private Button bouton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text=new TextView(null);
    text.setText("entrer votre login et mot de passe");
    final EditText editText1= new EditText(null);
    final EditText editText2=new EditText(null);
  final Button bouton= new Button("con");
    TableLayout x=new TableLayout(this);
    x.addView(text);
    x.addView(editText1);
    x.addView(editText2);
    x.addView(bouton);
    bouton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick (View v){
           if (((editText1.getText().toString().equals(login))&&(editText2.getText().toString().equals(pwd)))==true)
           {

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connection valide",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           if (v==bouton){
              final String requete="http://www.google.fr/search?q="+editText1.getText();
          Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(requete));
          startActivity(intent);}

       }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pas de Connection " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
               }
         }});


  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}
```

but when I try to run the application I get this error:

```
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:332)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3236)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3295)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:447)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:442)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:438)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.example.exercice1part2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-17 18:11:25.426: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     ... 11 more
11-17 18:15:40.177: I/Process(1028): Sending signal. PID: 1028 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onClickListener is an "anonymous inner class".  It can access variables it declares, variables in it's "containing class" (your Activity), package level class (not declared "public" in the current package) and public variables.

You declare and initialise editText2 in your onCreate method.  The onCreate method runs, finishes and destroys all of it's locally declared variables.  onCreate finishes before your onClickListener can run, since the UI is not built until after onCreate finishes. Therefore, the reference to editText2 no longer exists and you get the NPE.

To fix it, move the declaration to the class level, i.e before onCreate:

```
...
final EditText editText1
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
```

And initialise it inside onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
editText1= new EditText(this);
...
```

Good luck.

Comment: Ok I fixed that but my problem now is the display !! I don't see anything in MainActivity after I run the project!! it's empty no button , no EditText..

Comment: One question per question please.  Please accept this one as the answer to the original problem and start a new question for your display problem otherwise this post just fills up with comments and we have to debug your code line by line.

Comment: I found my error !! I forgot to put setContentView(x); !! thanks for your help :))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `TextView text=new TextView(null);` is correct.

Try and use `TextView text=new TextView(this);` instead.

Comment: Your logs show that the error comes from the 26th which refers to tne new TextView statement. You can try to change `this` to `getApplicationContext()`. Please, send us your logs after these changes.

Comment: this time the MainActivity is opened in the emulator but it's empty!!
and in the logCat I got this:
    11-17 21:05:43.017: E/Trace(1165): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    11-17 21:05:43.758: D/gralloc_goldfish(1165): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Comment: Please, can you edit your post and put your new logs ? (I'm afraid this kind of logs is not related to your problem)

Comment: 11-17 21:05:43.017: E/Trace(1165): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    11-17 21:05:43.758: D/gralloc_goldfish(1165): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Comment: Now I don't have any error in the logs but I have an error in the console which is "[2012-11-17 21:23:42 - exercice1part2] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front"

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, then, do a "Project > Clean".

Comment: I did that but I got the same earlier error 'E/Trace(897): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)'
btw this is the first time I create an android project and I remember that my teacher told us that nothing will appear in the MainActivity if we don't do a "thing" and I can't remember what was that "thing".

Comment: google `error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)` and you will find many workarrounds from stackoverflowers.

Comment: It works for me now !! I forgot to type the code  `setContentView(x);`
thanks alot for your help :))

Comment: If either Simon's or my solution helped, then please choose the answer. Otherwise, post the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

this is the the solution tha I found in the end and it works:

```
public package com.example.exercice1part2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String login="aaa";
private String pwd="bbb";
private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;
private TextView text;
private Button bouton;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TableLayout x=new TableLayout(this);
    setContentView(x);
    text =new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    text.setText("entrer votre login et mot de passe");
    editText1= new EditText(this);
    if (editText1.getText().toString().length()==0)
        editText1.setError("nom ne dépasse pas 10 caractère");
    editText2=new EditText(this);
    editText2.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    if (editText2.getText().toString().length()==0)
        editText2.setError("mot de passe ne dépasse pas 6 caractère");
  bouton= new Button(this);
  bouton.setText("connection" );

    x.addView(text);
    x.addView(editText1);
    x.addView(editText2);
    x.addView(bouton);
    bouton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick (View v){

           if (((editText1.getText().toString().equals(login))&&(editText2.getText().toString().equals(pwd)))==true)
           {

          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connection valide",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           if (v==bouton){
              final String requete="http://www.google.fr/search?q="+editText1.getText();
          Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(requete));
          startActivity(intent);}

       }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pas de Connection " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
               }

         }});


  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
   }
}
```

and thanks for every one who helped me :))